# How to create an low-level object file?

Tags: c, linux, linker, 64-bit, elf

Basically what I want is to create an object file (maybe x64 ELF one) with assembly code which could then be linked with other object files in order to create one executable. Also I would like to export some addresses from this object and also to import some from the other object files it will link to.

I'll be happy if it can target linux x64 (I'm using OpenSuse now) and can be used with some default linker (like 'ld' maybe).

*I want to make a compiler using 'C' language.*

Comment: You mean like `gcc -c`?

Answer (score 1):

Just generate assembly code, and use the assembler to convert to object format.